# MAMP PRO and the /private/etc/hosts file

Tags: mamp, hosts-file

It turns out that today i started trying MAMP PRO for Postfix SMTP.
But i had and have a nasty problem.
There's no way MAMP PRO 4.2.1 is allowed to overwrite the hosts file, and it needs to, so MAMP PRO doesn't work.
I found no clear answer in the internet and i tried already couple of solutions with no success, like recreating the file, erasing or commenting the 127.0.0.1 localhost line, among others.
Any ideas around? (I never had that problem with MAMP)

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Already fixed.  It was my mistake. The hosts file was renamed by textEdit to hosts.rtf without my knowledge. Once that was fixed everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Marcos Di Paolo method. I went into /etc/hosts/ and had seen that my hosts file had an extension added onto it (hosts~orig). Take the extension out and your Mamp Pro will work fine so it just says hosts. My Mamp is working 100% now.